# How do I create a specific amount of divs based on the number of letters given?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    function everything() {
      var words = ["dog", "coat", "cough", "coffee"] 
      var rand = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
      var single = rand.split("");
      var box = $("<div>" + single + "</div>");
      $("body").append(box);         
    }
```

I would like to know how to create the number of separate divs based on the amount of letters the random word was chosen.

How can I put each letter of the chosen word in its own seperate div box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to split and then join again:

```
var single = '<div>' + rand.split('').join('</div><div>') + '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

> You will need a `for-loop` to iterate through characters.

Try this:

```js
function everything() {
  var words = ["dog", "coat", "cough", "coffee"]
  var rand = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  var single = rand.split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < single.length; i++) {
    var box = $("<div>" + single[i] + "</div>");
    $("body").append(box);
  }
}
everything();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Or use `.html()`*

```js
function everything() {
  var words = ["dog", "coat", "cough", "coffee"]
  var rand = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  var single = rand.split("");
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < single.length; i++) {
    html += "<div>" + single[i] + "</div>";
  }
  $("body").html(html);
}
everything();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function everything() {
  var words = ["dog", "coat", "cough", "coffee"]
  var rand = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  for (var i = 0; i < rand.length; i++) {
     var box = "<div>" + rand.substring(i,i+1) + "</div>";
     $("body").append(box);
  }
}
everything();
```

you must include jquery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After `rand.split('')`, powerful Array methods are available.

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
function everything() {
    var words = ["dog", "coat", "cough", "coffee"];
    var rand = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    $("body").append(rand.split('').map(function(letter) {
        return $("<div>" + letter + "</div>");
    }).join(''));
}
```

Or [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
function everything() {
    var words = ["dog", "coat", "cough", "coffee"];
    var rand = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    $("body").append(rand.split('').reduce(function(str, letter) {
        return str + "<div>" + letter + "</div>";
    }, ''));
}
```

That said, both are overkill, in this case. Given that there's no transform of `letter` other than to wrap it, @Andy's solution is preferable.